# How to predict table sizes Oracle?

Tags: oracle, datatable

I'm trying to do a growth prediction on some tables I have and for that I've got to do some calculations on my row sizes, how many rows I generate by day and well.. the maths.

I'm calculating the average size of each row in my table as the sum of the average size of each field. So basicaly:

```
SELECT 'COL1' , avg(vsize(COL1)) FROM TABLE union
SELECT 'COL2' , avg(vsize(COL2)) FROM TABLE
```

Sum that up, multiply by the number of entries of a day and work the predictions from there.

Turns out that for one of the tables I've looked the resulting size is a lot smaller than I thought it would be and got me wondering if my method was right.

Also, I did not consider indexes sizes for my predictions - and of course I should.

My questions are:

1. Is this method I'm using reliable?
2. Tips on how could I work the predictions for the Indexes?

I've done my googling, but the methods I find are all about the segments and extends or else calculations based in the whole table. I will need the step with the actual row of my table to do the predictions (I have to analyse the data in the table in order to figure how many records a day).

And finally, this is an approximation. I know I'm missing some bytes here and there with overheads and stuff. I just want to make sure I'm only missing *bytes* and not *gigas* :)

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/estimate-a-database-size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Your method is sound to calculate the average size of a row. (Though be aware that if your column contains null, you should use `avg(nvl(vsize(col1), 0))` instead of `avg(vsize(COL1))`). However, it doesn't take into account the physical arrangement of rows.

First of all, it doesn't take into account the header info (from both blocks and rows): you can't fit 8k data into 8k blocks. See the documentation on [data block format](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/logical.htm#sthref306) for more information.

Then, rows are not always stored neatly packed. Oracle lets some space in each blocks so that the rows can grow when they are updated (governed by the `pctfree` parameter). Also when the rows are deleted the empty space is not reclaimed right away (if you're not using ASSM with locally managed tablespaces, the amount of free space required for a block to return to the list of available blocks depends on `pctused`).

If you already have some representative data in your table, you can estimate the amount of extra space you will need by comparing the space physically used (`all_tables.blocks*block_size` after having gathered statistics) to the average row length.

By the way Oracle can easily give you a good estimate of the average row length: gather statistics on the table and query `all_tables.avg_row_len`.

2) Most of the time (read: unless there is a bug or you fall into an atypical use of the index), the index will grow proportionaly to the number of rows.

If you have representative data, you can have a good estimation of its future size by multiplying its actual size by the relative growth of the number of rows.

Answer (score 4):

The last time Oracle [published their formulae for estimating the size of schema objects](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58397/apa.htm#808) was in Oracle 8.0, which means the linked document is ten years out of date.  However, I don't expect very much has changed in how Oracle reserves segment header, block header, or row header information.

Comment: Space use estimation guidelines are available for newer versions as well, e.g. the [Administrator's Guide for 11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/schema.htm#ADMIN11622) suggests using [DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_TABLE_COST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_space.htm#ARPLS68103), which relieves you of some manual calculations.